# How get access to Netwrok response area with Chrome DevTools Protocol?

Tags: python, google-chrome-devtools, network-protocols

I`m trying to get access to an area with a Network response
[image]

I`m using the following code, but it does not work.

```
import websocket
import json
from pprint import pprint
   
ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("ws://localhost:9222/devtools/page/5EC90A588BEC2DA0229988D28BA67495")
ws.send(json.dumps({"method": "Network.getResponseBody", "id": })) #  don`t know where i can find it
response = ws.recv()
pprint(response)
```

And I`m not sure if I do the right things.
So, does anybody know how to do this?

P.S. I know, I can make a direct request to API web-source and get JSON Object, but I need to make it with Chrome DevTools Protocol

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally found it!
U just need to use the following method: "Network.getResponseBody"